# Replicating the norwegian flag using CSS

Tags: css

so here I am trying to get some reviews from my code, where I have to replicate the norwegian flag using flexbox.

First to be sayed is that my teachers told me to divide the flag in two sections, where I have had to insert two of the four squares in eachone, but I ignored this since with declarations like `align-content: space-between;` I could send the four squares right to the corners and play with margins to adjust them, that's why I just created 4 containers (white squares) with its respective item (red squares).

Before I show my code, I want to tell that it was so diffuicult to me to deal with the size of the elements, first a try to use `flex-basis: ;` and `flex-grow: ;` to automatically give size to the squares, but this does'nt work for me, so I have to use `width: ;` and `height: ;`.

Due to all this I want to get reccomendations to improve my code or best alternatives to reach the objective and then a kind of explanation about the size of elements.

Here's the code:

```css
body{
    background-color: #00205B;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-between;
}
.white-square1, .white-square2, .white-square3, .white-square4{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.white-square1, .white-square3{
    margin: 0 50px 50px 0;
    height: 43.8vh;
    width: 25vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.white-square2, .white-square4{
    margin: 0 0 50px 50px;
    height: 43.8vh;
    width: 50vw;    
    flex-grow: 2;
}
.white-square3{
    margin: 50px 50px 0 0; 
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.white-square4{
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.red-square1, .red-square2, .red-square3, .red-square4{
    background-color: #BA0C2F;
}
.red-square1, .red-square3{
    margin: 0 50px 50px 0;
    height: 37.8vh;
    width: 25vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.red-square2, .red-square4{
    margin: 0 0 50px 50px;
    height: 37.8vh;
    width: 50vw;
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.red-square3{
    margin: 50px 50px 0 0; 
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.red-square4{
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Flexbox Actividad 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="white-square1">
        <div class="red-square1"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="white-square2">
        <div class="red-square2"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="white-square3">
        <div class="red-square3"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="white-square4">
        <div class="red-square4"></div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Quick implementation idea

Create a container `div` with two `div`s inside. Position those `div`s as a cross lust like in the Norwegian flag. After that give those `div`s a thick white border and the flag's red color would be simply the container `div`'s `background-color`.

#### Code review

- `Section`s are not an `appropriate` HTML element in this case. Use `div`'s instead.
- Do not style using `html` tags like `body`. Use CSS classes instead. Read about the `css specificity`
- `.red-square2, .red-square4{` this selector has both `margin` and `margin-righ` properties at once. `margin: a b c d` should be enough.
- Tidy up your CSS. In one line You style `.red-square3` and some lines below You style the same element. Why? Can't you use one CSS rule for that? :)

#### Improvement ideas

- Move the CSS color to variables and place them in a separate file.

Comment: I'll try your quick implementation idea, I did't think about it and sounds interesting.

Comment: I'll try your quick implementation idea, I did't think about it and sounds interesting.

About [CODE REVIEW]: 
Where do I could read about how to use properly the semanthic tags? I´m reading HTML & CSS by Jon Duckett and don´t remember such recomendation, and actually it's kind of confusing how to use the other semanthic tags.

So it's better to add a class to the body tag and add style to that class instead to the body tag?

I did't notice that, thx.

It's because first, I add declarations in general and then modify values according to my needs.

Comment: By definition, section is the wrapping element that should begin with some kind of a heading <h1> etc..

`The <section> element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content. Each section should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the <section> element.`

source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element

Comment: If my response was helpful - consider marking it as resolved :) Have a nice day

Comment: On Code Review, it's customary to wait a couple of days before handing out checkmarks. Don't sweat it.

Comment: THX Adam, I was waiting for new responses, but your answer was so helpful for me, so I marked as resolved, thanks for your time. <3

Comment: Non problemo :) Always happy to help. Have a nice day and weekend :)